# How to convert a leapyear date into datetime in a For loop?

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, leap-year

I am using  a for loop to convert all the date in the dataframe to datetime.
But since one of the date is in leap year it is giving the error.

```
DeciYear = []
for i in range(0,len(data_ncs)):
   print(i) 
   d=datetime(data_ncs.Year.iloc[i],data_ncs.Month.iloc[i],data_ncs.Day.iloc[i],data_ncs.Hour.iloc[i],    data_ncs.Minute.iloc[i],int(data_ncs.Seconds.iloc[i]))
```

ERROR:

```
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

The date which is causing the error `datetime(1991,2,29,12,12,12)`
How come I could override this error?

Comment: 1991 was not a leap year, the error is valid.

Comment: @MrFuppes , But when using to_datetime, i am facing some problem with some old dates which starting from the year 1550? is it normal?

Comment: Ok that would be out of range for the pandas nanosecond timestamp; I did not realize that this other question was from you ^^